# iTextSharp - add text directly to PDF when open in the browser - C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am filling form fields on a PDF with iTextSharp. The user enters data into a web-based form, then clicks a <kbd>Create PDF</kbd> button. The PDF then opens in the browser with the user entered text displaying in the applicable areas of the PDF.

I would like to allow the user to then manually add additional information into form fields directly on the PDF within the browser. We do not collect all information necessary in the web-based form; the user currently prints the PDF and writes the additional information in.

Comment: Just an idea, but would it be better for customer experience if you _did_ collect all data upfront?

Comment: Collecting all data upfront would be betterfor the user, but time-consuming from a maintenance standpoint. Hundreds of forms have the same 20-30 basic questions (what is collected through UI) and then each form has a number of additional questions particular to that form. We fill the forms with the basic data, then ask the user to fill in the rest.

Comment: I am missing the question. What is the question here? Generate a fillable form as the PDF fie using iTextSharp and display that. iText can certainly be used to create form fields in the PDF.

Comment: I have a pdf with form fields on it. Some of those fields are then filled with data entered through a web-based form (First Name, Last Name, etc.). We do not have data entry fields on the web-based form for some of the other fields (weight) - We would like to give the user the ability to manually enter the weight directly into the PDF though the browser and save.

Comment: Define "save". Do you mean "submit to the server"? If so, please re-explain the question as you'd be asking something so trivial that Kevin nor me wouldn't know what to answer. Do you mean "save locally on the local hard disk"? If so, you need a reader-enabled PDF and that's what this question is about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894689/adding-enable-for-commenting-adobe-reader-using-acrobat

Comment: I may have complicated my question by adding the words 'and save'. Saving would be great, but primary question is "Can a user enter information into a pdf that is open in a browser, or must it be downloaded to local machine and opened with acrobat to enter information?"