# How do I remove link annotations from a PDF using iText?

Tags: c#, itext

Here i want to remove Annotation(Link, Text, ..) from PDF permanently using iTextSharp.

Already i have tried

```
AnnotationDictionary.Remove(PdfName.LINK);
```

But that Link annotations exist in that PDF.

**Note:**

I want remove particular selected Annotations(Link, Text, ..),
For Example i want remove Link Annotation with the URI as www.google.com, remaining Link Annotations i want to be retain as per exist.

Comment: Please download RUPS and take a look at the internal structure of your PDFs. You don't need to remove the `Link` entry, you need to remove the *complete annotation dictionary* containing the `Link`! You'll find RUPS here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrups

Comment: ya i am understand that, that's only i am coming to ask. how can i remove one Annotation Completely from the PDF file? by using iTextSharp

Comment: Ya I got the answer for my question. Your link is very useful

Comment: I upvoted your answer. I was in a meeting the last 2 hours, so I didn't have the time to write a snippet myself, but I'm happy to see that my pointer helped.

Comment: Surely you welcome, I need you kind of people support to learn, develop and discus our knowledge. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer for my question.

**Sample Code:**

```
//Get the current page
PageDictionary = R.GetPageN(i);

//Get all of the annotations for the current page
Annots = PageDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

foreach (PdfObject A in Annots.ArrayList)
{
//code to check the annotation 

//remove the annotation
Annots.Remove(int idx);

}
```

Comment: After empty `Annots`, how do you save the pdf? It seems `R` is a pdf reader and I see no `PDFStamper` or `PDFWriter` here, can you add the saving code?

Answer (score -1):

````
        Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(fileloc)
        For i = 1 To pdfReader.NumberOfPages
            Dim pageDict As PdfDictionary = pdfReader.GetPageN(i)
            Dim annots As PdfArray = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS)
            Dim newAnnots As PdfArray = New PdfArray()
            If annots IsNot Nothing Then
                For j As Integer = 0 To annots.Size() - 1
                    Dim annotDict As PdfDictionary = annots.GetAsDict(i)
                    If Not PdfName.LINK.Equals(annotDict.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE)) Then
                        newAnnots.Add(annots.GetAsDict(j))
                    End If
                Next
                pageDict.Put(PdfName.ANNOTS, newAnnots)
            End If
        Next
        Dim pdfStamper As PdfStamper = Nothing
        Dim extension = Path.GetExtension(fileloc)
        Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileloc)
        Dim filePath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileloc)
        fileloc = filePath + "\" + filename + "new" + extension
        pdfStamper = New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream(fileloc, FileMode.Create))
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = False
        pdfStamper.Close()
        pdfReader.Close()
    End Sub```
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This answer should be improved by adding in a description on what the code is doing, or an explanation of why this solution works.